# Swift simulator looks different from storyboard

Tags: swift, autolayout

i use autolayout with stackview for my autolayout, and looks like the ui from storyboard and from simulator when i run the app is different, can anyone tell me why? 
[image: Simulator]

[image: Storyboard]

it shows that the simulator and storyboard looks different. can anyone tell me why and how to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are wrong. Thats why, it looks different. 
1st thing, you should keep in mind is to use scrollview in such type of forms. Append you view in your scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your constraints for the StackView inside the Photo view has incorrect height at runtime. At the run time it looks like the orange view with the Save button is the same height as the top cyan colour view.

The easiest way to fix this is to embed the Profile Picture ImageView and the Change Photo button inside a UIView and give the ImageView and the UIButton a fixed height.

Comment: i already embed in into a uiview, and i separate 3 individual view, and i put it all together into stack view, but the problem still consist

Comment: @afipermana Did you try to give the button and the image view a fixed height after embedding them in UIViews?

Comment: i already fix it, you kinda rite i have to have fixed height....thanks mate